# Wrong apk getting installed on devices from play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have published 2 apps with same package, one for phone and other for tablet (versioncode of tablet is higher). I am differentiating them using following manifest entry

Tablet manifest:
< supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />

Phone manifest:
< supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Play store is distributing tablet build to few phone (samsung s7 edge, s8 etc.) and only for few users (not all s7, s8).

The biggest mystery is few s7, s8 users are getting phone apk and few getting tablet, which i am not getting why.

Am i missing something here? any help/input very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here

[Multiple APK support for phone and tablet android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946835/multiple-apk-support-for-phone-and-tablet-android)

There are two readme's linked. Maybe this can help you.
They have also other manifest settings than you. Write me if you have more questions.